# Designing a bullet proof ETL job to aggregate data using Java, SQL and (possibly) Spring-batch

Tags: aggregate, batch-processing, etl, spring-batch

I have to rewrite a legacy ETL Job (5 years old, grown gradually) that aggregates data from an Oracle DB to mySQL DB for invoicing and reporting purposes. The existing job is written in Java using a custom built framework. The framework can be used to read, process and write data from Datasource A to Datasource B. The configuration is XML based and in some ways similar to Spring batch. These are the core features of the framework

- A Job needs a source and destination datasource to be specified. A materialized view serves as the source table and an SQL query that is very complex is run against it inorder to aggregate.
- Columns to be copied from source and to be saved in destination have to be specified in XML
- In the Processor, there is the possibility to validate and/or transform the data
- SQL is generated by the framework and also transaction is managed by it
- If the job fails, it can be restarted for the given time period(a month usually) and it would clean up the last run and redo its work from the scratch

The main bottlenecks that we have with the current solution are the following:

1. XML has become cluttered with many special business rules that are expressed as SQL snippets - not so easy to test or maintain
2. In Production, job is run monthly and as the volume has increased, it is getting slower and increasingly difficult to run it once a month and get the result on the same business day, given the tight deadlines we have from Customers.

I am in a dilemma how to redesign this job. I can rewrite the Job in Spring batch or just another custom solution - this would help me to get rid of the XML with embedded SQLs and move the business rules to a more maintainable SQL or another neat testable and maintainable service. 
But how to solve the second problem? I am thinking of running the job every day instead of monthly and then use another monthly job to aggregate over the daily - this would help us to get a daily feedback of errors and we can fix them and restart. But here it gets tricky. As each input row is an aggregated result based on group by over several columns, i cannot imagine how i could just "read" those failed rows again. I may have to restart the complete process and this is also inefficient. At the moment, I am thinking of one solution: Instead of having a materialized view that just joins many tables, I would have **the materialized view present itself with aggregated data** as well. Each row in this table will also have a technical PK. Then the job will read from this view, process data, and write. Errors will be caught and logged into another table along with the PK of the row which caused the problem. Is this a good way to design a job that copies data across databases, especially when source data is more than a simple select?

Answer (score 1):

As a solution for your problem #2, I could suggest switching from ETL to ELT. You can daily extract (E) the raw data from the source system, load (L) it into the stage area of your data warehouse and then transform (T) it by aggregating the data from your stage area on the monthly basis.

What kind of errors are you getting? Do those errors predominantly occur during the extraction of the data from the source system or when aggregating it? In any case, with the proposed approach you can keep the copy of the daily data extracts and then backfill for the missing dates when the data in the source system is cleaned or repaired. If the errors occur during aggregation, you can test aggregate partial results on the daily basis and get notified about the problems early, rather than on the day of the delivery deadline.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion. The errors are not recoverable, related to the quality of input data or some other config. issues, but can only be logged. Based on the current architecture, it is not helpful to skip and continue as the job can be restarted only from the scratch, so lets say a monthly job will fail if there is some data problem with data on last day of the month. Your proposal to ELT on a daily basis - I'll seriously consider and see whether it'll scale. In that case, I'll have to replicate the source completely rather than just the aggregated output which may not be acceptable to DBA.